# why does window.open(''); usually work as expected; but sometimes fails?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, bookmarklet

*My Test Case*:

- I browse to a webpage;
- open DevTools console;
- and execute `windows.open('');`

it usually works fine and I get a new blank window.

But if I browse to [NSFW] `spankbang.com` and do the same; it fails.

1-2yrs ago I wrote a bookmarklet for YouTube. It grabs `<meta>` tags and `<script type="application/json">` blocks and dumps them to a blank page. It has worked great on YouTube and a ton of other sites.
But, today I tried using it on [NSFW] `spankbang.com` and it fails!

This is on Windows 10 Pro using Edge.

Comment: So what does dev tools do instead? And if it does nothing, what does `console.log(window.open)` show? Because any global and be trivially overwritten to no longer work. Though on that note, don't use `window.open` for opening new tabs to begin with; create an `a` element with `target="_blank"` and an `href` to whatever needs to open, and then trigger that on the JS side so that the browser sees a normal navigation action, adding a normal history entry, etc.

Comment: The website can override the `window.open` function simply by setting the "open" property of the `window` object to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because they delete the open fonction at this website

```
// the open fonction are deleted
delete window.open
// throw error
window.open('')
```

and you can get it back like this

```
console.log(typeof window.open); // "function"
delete window.open;
console.log(typeof window.open); // "undefined"

//  "insert an iframe into DOM, to take window.open from its contentWindow"
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
window.open = iframe.contentWindow.open;
console.log(typeof window.open); // "function"
// it work now!
window.open('')
```

and dont post adulte link here

Comment: Lapwood: I'll try your work-around shortly... I never would have thought of that. Thanks.

yeah,... I know I shouldn't post adult sites (and certainly why I tagged it NSFW and did not make into a link). But what am I/we supposed to do if the failure can only be reproduced there??? Is there any politically correct way to handle this?

Comment: Excellent solution using an <iframe>'s window.open() function!

Comment: it work i always try solution before i poste an anser then you can mark it as solved

Comment: (sorry... forgot about marking it solved. done.) thanks again!